# Sequelize proper inheritance from Model, findOne() does not work

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

When I extend class which is extended from Sequelize.Model I get wrong result from .findAll(), findOne() and other `finding` methods.

I'm trying to create a class extending Sequelize.Model:

```
class NestedSetModel extends Model {
  constructor () {
    super(arguments)
  }
static init (attributes, options) {
    const nestedAttributes = {
      ...attributes,
// other fields: parentUID etc
}
}
```

It includes common fields like `parentUID`, `childsUIDs` for storing tree inside my DB.
Then I want to inherit other class from it and add some custom fields like `name` or some:

```
class CategoryModel extends NestedSetModel {}
```

When I try to search using findOne I get this:

```
category {
    dataValues:
     { id: '5cec90f7-d5d7-4153-adad-acbb772ce7f5', // random UID
       parentUID: null,
       childrenUIDs: [] },
}
```

which seems like an empty instance of NestedSetModel

Comment: By the way `.create()` works just perfect...

Comment: What does your ` findOne` query look it? (please post in original question)